# How to add a success message after django allauth change password view has returned response

Tags: python, django, password-recovery, django-allauth

I am using django allauth to my django project for all my authentication related functionality,
so now I want to implement `password change` functionality, so just copied the django allauth templates to my `templates/allauth/account/password_change.html` and customized with my custom design and has the form something like below

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="" action="{% url 'account_change_password' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="alert alert-success  password_changed">
          You have Successfully changed your Password!
     </div>
     {{form.as_p}} 
     <div class="span12 pagination-centered marg_lftnone">
          <input id="save_new_password" name="action" type="submit" class="btn btn-large big_btn marg_tp38 marg_btm38" value="Save Password">
     </div>
</form>
```

So with the above template the password changing functionality has been working fine and redirecting to current page, but what I want is when redirected to current page, I want to show a `message div` like above about informing that `you have changed password successfully`.

So how to display and error message after the password has been changed successfully and redirected to the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allauth emits `password_changed` signal, so you need to hook up a receiver. In your models.py add the following:

```
from allauth.account.signals import password_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib import messages

@receiver(password_changed)
def password_change_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    messages.success(request, 'You have Successfully changed your Password!.')
```

Then use your message inside template as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates).

Comment: great thanks for the answer, but its displaying me the error that `AssertionError: Signal receivers must accept keyword arguments (**kwargs).`. so the function should receive a **kwargs like `def password_change_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):`

Comment: and more over the messages are displaying the errors div `three times` and dont know y ?

Comment: add **kwargs, it is indeed required. messages are stored [in session by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages), so you basically changed pwd three times, and those messages are displayed now.

Comment: Allauth automatically adds messages on events, like password change - https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L362 If you want to use your own messages, you need to use a custom adapter, and override it's `add_messages` method to do nothing, so that you don't get multiple messages

Answer (score 2):

In django-allauth the messages are stored as txt files in `django-allauth/allauth/templates/account/messages/`.

You can copy the `password_changed.txt` file into your `templates/account/messages/`and customize the following code:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% blocktrans %}Password successfully changed.{% endblocktrans %}
```

[Link to the password_changed.txt file on github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/messages/password_changed.txt)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is also the recommended way to customize messages per the official [alltauth documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#messages)

Comment: As mariodev commented below Allauth emits password_changed signal, so you need to hook up a receiver or change the template.

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple way is to add this piece of code into the template `password_change.html`

```
<h1>{% translate "Change Password" %}</h1>   
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.tags == 'success' %}          
      {% translate 'Password successfully changed.' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}   
<form method="POST" ...>
```